# Alienware M14x going real hot in Idle

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling, temperature

I have an Alienware M14x which I started noticing the fans going extremely high at idle, pretty much right after a boot too.

I downloaded HWMonitor to check what's up and it turns out it's at about 75-85 degrees Celsius in idle. If i run Chrome or something it reaches 95 degrees.

Theses are the things I've tried to solve the problem:

1. Reinstall the OS, same problem in Win 7 and Win 8.1
2. Blow the PC clean of all dust with compressed air.
3. I disassembled the whole PC, turns out the thermal paste on both the GPU and CPU was totally dry, so I cleaned both the CPU, GPU and the heatsink and applied new thermal paste to the CPU and GPU. Then reassembled the comp.

This did lower the degrees by about 10 degrees, so it was at 75-85 degrees at idle before, now it's at 65-75 degrees in idle. However, I was expecting a lot more change. I mean being around 75 degrees Celsius in idle is still too much.

Any ideas on something else I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cooling paste is the main issue here. You've followed, pretty much the same steps of troubleshooting a hot CPU as I have, so let's presume that the fans and air filters are clean now:

When applying thermal paste, use as little as possible, just enough to make sure the heatsink and the cpu/gpu gets a nice mating. I use the end of a ruler to make sure I scrape off any excess. Too much actually causes worse cooling, as it isn't as thermally conductive as the metal in the CPU/GPU and heat sink. In addition, the brand of thermal paste matters. Recommending a brand is offtopic for this, but you usually get what you pay for.

**PS:** The reason why it was dry to begin with is because of the heat itself. This often happens when fans and filters clog up: Temperature starts to climb, and the thermal paste becomes like dry clay, compounding the heat issue. You should clean out fans and filters on a regular basis. I do it once every 6 months. (More often if in a dusty or linty environment).